# What's a word meaning "at the expense of"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What's a word meaning *"at the expense of"* so I can shorten the following sentence:

> Due to the influence of money in politics, concessions are made at the expense of citizenry.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you explain why *at the expense of* is unsuitable? Have you consulted a thesaurus?

Comment: @choster, Thank you. I need a shorter word/phrase than *at the expense of*. [I have consulted a thesaurus](http://ask.reference.com/web?s=t&q=expense%20of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, [***to the detriment of***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+detriment+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20detriment%20of%3B%2Cc0).

> detriment: a damage or loss [WordNet Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/detriment)

A shorter alternative, though, would be to use the preposition ***on***.

> on: to the detriment of [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/on)
>
> *Concessions are made on citizenry*.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote (not enough points)!

Comment: Good expression, but I don't think it's shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

It mean at the loss of something. As [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+the+expense+of) defines:

> With the loss of something

To paraphrase this:

> Due to the influence of money in politics, concessions are made **with
>   the loss** of citizenry.

Answer (score 0):

While impacts could be positive, the context is already sufficient to establish the negativity. Thus:

> Due to the influence of money in politics, concessions are made **impacting** citizenry

or

> Due to the influence of money in politics, concessions are made **which impact** citizenry

PS. *citizenry* is unusual, even in political science. I'd just use *citizens*. Alternatives are *the people* or *the population*.